# Firebase Recycler option not retriving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can get data using value event listener but when i am using FirebaseRecyclerOptions i am not getting any data. When i set debug in my code datasnapshot is 0
Here is my code

```
 @NonNull
 protected RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatModel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatModel>() //sChatQuery=database.getReference("comments").child("story"+did).limitToLast(15);;
                        .setQuery(sChatQuery, ChatModel.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();


        return new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, ChatHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                return new ChatHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatModel model) {
                holder.bind(model);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {

            }
        };
    }
```

And ChatModel class to get firebase data is

```
public class ChatModel {
    String email;
    String message;
    String time;
    String name;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And firebase database which i am trying to retrieve is given below

[image]

Comment: do you have any node before `comments`?

Comment: yes, i have anotther node before comments

Comment: are you using the other nodes in your query?

Comment: What the value of `sChatQuery`?

Comment: I am not using any other node in my query, sChatQuery=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()..getReference("comments")..child("story6").limitToLast(15)